# What is timezone format and how to convert it to a normal abbreviation in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on an iOS app and after networking, I get JSON back with a timezone property formatted as some kind of number. Here is a picture

[image]

What is that number for timezone and how do I convert it something I can use in my app like "GMT" for example?

Comment: I guess that's number of seconds from GMT. You can use https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timezone/2293718-init

Comment: _"...something I can use in my app"_, what is that something and what do you need it for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`32400` (seconds) is the equivalent of 9 hours.

You get a `TimeZone` instance with

```
TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: timezone)
```

which is GMT+0900

However you cannot get the identifier like `JST` just from the seconds because there are multiple identifiers for the same amount of seconds.

Comment: Then use `abbreviation` to get something like "GMT". This one isn't GMT, though. It's JST.

Comment: The TimeZone init that uses abbreviation requires a string. How would I get a string from the secondsFromGMT init?

Comment: @Tomas Sadly, you can't — there are many time zones with the same offset from GMT, so there's no mapping that makes sense. You could theoretically use the `country` code _along_ with the offset from GMT, but there's no built-in way to do that; you'd have to maintain mappings yourself. (But like Joakim mentions above in a comment, it really depends on what you're actually trying to do. More detail would help.)

Comment: I'm making a weather app and I want the time to be specific to the wherever the user searches. So if it's 8pm where the user is at and 4am in Tokyo(user searched), I want Tokyo's time to be displayed instead of the time of the user's location.

Comment: The `secondsFromGMT` value is sufficient to calculate the local time of the location.

Comment: (The above is true assuming that `secondsFromGMT` correctly reflects the current offset from GMT for that time zone, taking into account things like DST. It might be worth confirming for different locations around the world that are currently in DST or not, to be sure. Not all APIs are respectful of that.)

Comment: secondsFromGMT does indeed work! and I will take into account DST as I continue building the app.

Comment: @ItaiFerber The API is openweathermap which provides accurate data and considers DST.